# Use of loops (example, for) in the conditional arguments of numpy.where

Tags: arrays, numpy, for-loop, matrix, where-clause

I have a matrix "x" and an array "index".
I just want to find the position (row number) of the "index" array in the matrix "x".
Example:

```
x = np.array([[0, 0],
       [1, 0],
       [2, 0],
       [0, 1],
       [1, 1],
       [2, 1],
       [0, 2],
       [1, 2],
       [2, 2],
       [0, 3],
       [1, 3],
       [2, 3],])

index = [2,1]
```

Here if I use the code:
`np.where((x[:,0]==index[0]) & (x[:,1]==index[1]))[0]`
it is working.

But if I have the matrix "x" with N number of columns (instead of 2), I have to use loop inside the np.where arguments. I tried this:
`np.where((for b in range(2):(x[:,b]==index[b]) & (x[:,b]==index[b])))[0]`

Then it shows "invalid syntax" error.
Can you please help me regarding this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `where` is only as good as its argument, which is evaluated in full before being passed to the `where` function:

```
In [292]: np.where((x[:,0]==index[0]) & (x[:,1]==index[1]))[0]
Out[292]: array([5], dtype=int64)
```

The condition is a boolean array:

```
In [293]: (x[:,0]==index[0]) & (x[:,1]==index[1])
Out[293]: 
array([False, False, False, False, False,  True, False, False, False,
       False, False, False])
```

Looks like you tried to create a `for loop`:

```
for b in range(2):
      (x[:,b]==index[b]) & (x[:,b]==index[b])
```

Using that as argument is not valid python.  You could create a function that does

```
def foo(x,index):
    res = []
    for b in ....
         res.append(...)
    return res
```

But a simpler syntax is list comprehension:

```
In [294]: [x[:,i]==index[i] for i in range(2)]
Out[294]: 
[array([False, False,  True, False, False,  True, False, False,  True,
        False, False,  True]),
 array([False, False, False,  True,  True,  True, False, False, False,
        False, False, False])]
```

and the arrays can be combined with a `np.all`:

```
In [295]: np.all([x[:,i]==index[i] for i in range(2)], axis=0)
Out[295]: 
array([False, False, False, False, False,  True, False, False, False,
       False, False, False])
```

But as others show you don't need to iterate.  Let the (n,2) `x` broadcast against the (2,) `index`:

```
In [296]: x==index
Out[296]: 
array([[False, False],
       [False, False],
       [ True, False],
       [False,  True],
       [False,  True],
       [ True,  True],
       [False, False],
       [False, False],
       [ True, False],
       [False, False],
       [False, False],
       [ True, False]])

In [297]: (x==index).all(axis=1)
Out[297]: 
array([False, False, False, False, False,  True, False, False, False,
       False, False, False])
```

Answer (score 1):

**The following code will handle both if `index` be a list or a numpy array and if contains more than one index array in `index`, not just one**:

```
x = np.array([[0, 0, 7],
              [1, 0, 8],
              [2, 3, 11],
              [0, 1, 1],
              [1, 1, 9],
              [2, 1, 4],      # <--
              [0, 2, 7],
              [1, 2, 3],
              [2, 1, 4],      # <--
              [2, 2, 1],
              [0, 3, 2],
              [1, 3, 11],     # <--
              [1, 3, 8],
              [2, 3, 8],])

index = np.array([[2, 1, 4], [1, 3, 11]])    # --> can be list index = [2, 1, 4]
```

it can be done by:

```
np.where((x == np.atleast_2d(index)[:, None]).all(-1))[1]
# [ 5  8 11]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `broadcasting`:

```
np.where((x == np.array(index).reshape(1, -1)).all(1))
```

or even:

```
np.where((x == np.array(index)[None, :]).all(1))
```

both results in:

```
(array([5], dtype=int64),)
```