# Add a new axis if a numpy array is 1D, to convert it into 2D (shape: (1, n)) without if conditions

Tags: python, numpy

I want to write a code that will use a numpy array that can be 1D array or 2D. For avoiding related errors due to incompatibility of the array shapes with the code body, I want to convert 1D array to 2D if it was 1D, So if:

```
arr1 = np.array([2, 1, 4])                  # shape: (3,)
arr2 = np.array([[2, 1, 4], [1, 3, 11]])    # shape: (2,3)
```

I am seeking for a way, if there is, that the code automatically detect the shapes and convert that to the desired one `(1, n)` if that was 1D, without external if conditions (e.g. with some numpy reshaping repeatedly or …):

```
arr1 = np.array([[2, 1, 4]])                # shape: (1,3)   <-- modified
arr2 = np.array([[2, 1, 4], [1, 3, 11]])    # shape: (2,3)   it is not modified
```

I know it can be achieved easily with if condition in 2 lines, but I am curious if it can be handled by numpy itself:

```
if arr.ndim == 1:
    arr= arr[None, :]      # --> shape = (1, n)
```

Also, I would appreciate for any opinion about is it preferable to use this way instead *if condition*?

Comment: [`np.atleast_2d`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.atleast_2d.html)? Well, it's implemented in python and guess what it does internally.

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny exactly, thanks. unfortunately I didn't see this before.

Comment: @Ali-Sh - I was a little bit too fast, please check the source code. Not exactly without conditions.

Comment: While avoiding `for` loops generally improves speed, `if` steps aren't costly.  So it doesn't usually matter whether you write them yourself, bury them in a function, or a call a function that does it.

Comment: `np.array(..., ndmin=2, copy=False)` is another option.  But you may not need to explicitly convert `arr1` to 2d.  In `broadcasting` situations, (3,) and (1,3) behave the same.

Comment: @hpaulj Thanks for the explanations. Because I need to use some other reshaping or adding axis in next steps of the codes, `arr1` shape seems to need to be converted to `(1, n)`. I have faced to it in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72703905/13394817).